# Media query not working at all

Tags: html, css, media

I'm playing around creating a User information display on my website which I want to be responsive. I've used media queries before and never had any issues... however, anything I try hasn't worked, including changing id's to classes and playing with the div layout (eg absolute, relative...).

This is my css:

```
    #profile_container {
        position: relative; margin: 0 auto;
            top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1400px; height: 180px;  overflow: hidden; 
            background: rgba(237,237,237,1);

             }

             /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */

#profile_container {
        position: relative; margin: 0 auto;
            top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 300px; height: 100px;  overflow: hidden; 
            background: rgba(237,237,237,1);

             }
}
```

And this is my html with my other classes. The other classes don't contain any information on width and only have text attributes.

```
<div id="profile_container">
        <div class="profile_picture_large round_profile_pic_large">
        <img src="images/profiletest.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="profile_followers_rotate">24 <div class="profile_followers_rotate_small">followers!</div></div>

        <div class="welcome_text">Hello...</div>
        <div class="profile_name">Andy Rob Robinson</div>
```

Comment: please check that you add your css file correctly,  and it's working for me....

Comment: Also note... need a closing tag to your 
    <div id="profile_container">

Answer (score 1):

Try using Google Chrome and use its Developer tools.
To see your media queries then change the device to iPhone 5 then back to ipad 3-4. You should see them change.

If you want to see them change when you resize the browser then use

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width: 320px)
and (max-widht: 480px)
```